# nest mysql statements - runs only one loop?

Tags: php, mysql

Not too sure why this happening, it's never happened before, but somehow I can seem to figure this one.

```
$listing = $mySql->query("SELECT * FROM `ERRVER` as ev JOIN RELIST as rl on rl.Property_id=ev.Property_id WHERE ev.Corrected =1 AND (ev.Fieldname = 'City' || ev.Fieldname = 'StreetName' || ev.Fieldname = 'StreetNumber')");
    while ($record = $listing->fetchAssoc()) {

         $Location_id=$record['Location_id'];
          if ($record['Fieldname']=='City') {
               $sql="Update RELOC SET City='$record[Real_Value]' WHERE Location_id=$Location_id";
          }
          if ($record['Fieldname']=='StreetNumber') {
               $sql="Update RELOC SET StreetNumber='$record[Real_Value]' WHERE Location_id=$Location_id";
          }
          if ($record['Fieldname']=='StreetName') {
               $sql="Update RELOC SET StreetName='$record[Real_Value]' WHERE Location_id=$Location_id";
          }
          trace($sql);

      if ($update=$mySql->query($sql)) {
        $sql2="Update ERRVER SET Corrected=-1 WHERE Error_id=$record[Error_id]";
      trace($sql2);
      $update2=$mySql->query($sql2);

      }



 }
```

If I don't have the `$update` and just do an `echo $sql`, it works perfectly, but the moment I have an `$update` it just give me one loop? I know, I'm missing something, just don't know what.

Comment: Can I assume `Real_Value` is a constant? or do you miss some quotes?

Comment: You better first indent your code correctly. This can resolve multiple problems.

Comment: @Raptor Real_Value is a column in the database ... hence ... $record[Real_Value]

Comment: @CommuSoft Indents are not the issue .... no errors there ...

Comment: @NMFSDF: true, but it's a good habit to simply indent code properly, it is an investment that pays off enormously.

Comment: @CommuSoft okay done it .....

Comment: I am not sure why some one would -1 the question ... enough research and testing was done and since i couldnt figure the answer out was the main reason i put it here in the first place ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$listing = $mySql->query("SELECT * FROM `Error_Verify` as ev JOIN Real_Listing as rl on rl.Property_id=ev.Property_id WHERE ev.Corrected =1 AND (ev.Fieldname = 'City')");
    while ($record = $listing->fetchAssoc()) {

             $Location_id[]=$record['Location_id'];
             $Value[]=$record['Real_Value'];
             $errorid[]=$record['Error_id'];
     }
     for ($i=0;$l<count($Location_id);$i++) {
         $sql="Update Real_Location SET City='$Value[$i]' WHERE Location_id=$Location_id[$i]";
         trace($sql);
         if ($mySql->query($sql)) {
                $sql2="Update Error_Verify SET Corrected=-1 WHERE Error_id=$errorid[$i]";
                trace($sql2);
                $mySql->query($sql2);                
         }
     }
```

while the above works ..... and i knoew it would work... i still am not sure why the original code does not work ... nested  mysql queries is not a new thing ... still i leave the question up for grabs ,,,